# JPA / eclipse-link 2.6.0 / mysql : incorrect generated table name

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I created two tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instanceOfClass")
public class InstanceOfClass {
(...)
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<InstanceOfDataProperty> getDataProperties() {
        return dataProperties;
    }
(...)
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instanceOfDataProperty")
public class InstanceOfDataProperty  {
    (...)
    @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="instance_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    public InstanceOfClass getInstance()
        {
        return this.instance;
        }
    (...)
 }
```

when getDataProperties() is called, I get the following error in the log

```
Call: SELECT t1.id, t1.smallContent, t1.VALUE, t1.INSTANCE_id,t1.prop_id, t1.LARGECONTENT_id FROM instanceOfClass_instanceOfDataProperty t0, instanceOfDataProperty t1 WHERE ((t0.InstanceOfClass_id = ?) AND (t1.id = t0.dataProperties_id)) bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="file:/path/to/WEB-INF/classes/_jdbc/mydao" referenceClass=InstanceOfDataProperty sql="SELECT t1.id, t1.smallContent, t1.VALUE, t1.INSTANCE_id, t1.prop_id, t1.LARGECONTENT_id FROM instanceOfClass_instanceOfDataProperty t0, instanceOfDataProperty t1 WHERE ((t0.InstanceOfClass_id = ?) AND (t1.id = t0.dataProperties_id))")
```

(....)
   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user_me.instanceOfClass_instanceOfDataProperty' doesn't exist

where does this **user_me.instanceOfClass_instanceOfDataProperty** comes from ? how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the `mappedBy` value for the `@OneToMany` annotation in your `InstanceOfClass` entity, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instanceOfClass")
public class InstanceOfClass {
(...)
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="instanceOfClass")
    public List<InstanceOfDataProperty> getDataProperties() {
        return dataProperties;
    }
(...)
}
```

where `instanceOfClass` should be the name of the getter in the InstanceOfDataProperty class.

From the [JavaEE7 pdf](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwj51Ke_tZfHAhUDvXIKHQBnAcY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavaee%2F7%2FJEETT.pdf&ei=UuDEVfnjOoP6ygOAzoWwDA&usg=AFQjCNG7rIQeAdBU131cf_a81eCPBxkcmw&sig2=AcWTcD8JgZxU4ruELkTPqA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGQ), chapter 37.1.5.1:

> Bidirectional relationships must follow these rules.
>
> The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning side by using
>   the mappedBy element of the @OneToOne, @OneToMany, or @ManyToMany
>   annotation.
>
> The mappedBy element designates the property or field in
>   the entity that is the owner of the relationship. The many side of
>   many-to-one bidirectional relationships must not define the mappedBy
>   element. The many side is always the owning side of the relationship.

I did a quick test, with the entities Person and Address (1:N). First I left out the `mappedBy`, and a table named `Person_Address` has been created. After adding the `mappedBy`, a table `Address` had been created.

Comment: thanks. I added `mappedBy="instanceOfClass"`, I get : `the attribute [dataProperties] in entity class [class blablabala.InstanceOfClass] has a mappedBy value of [instanceOfClass] which does not exist in its owning entity class [class blablabala.InstanceOfDataProperty]. If the owning entity class is a @MappedSuperclass, this is invalid, and your attribute should reference the correct subclass.. Please see server.log for more details.`

Comment: Ah, I see your getter in InstanceOfDataProperty is named getInstance. So your mappedBy shuoldbe “instance“